# VBA - Copy filtered data values from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy, clipboard

I copy large amounts of filtered data (visible data and values only) from one workbook to another but the process is very slow.  I would like to try bypassing the clipboard to see if that improves the speed but I keep getting the error `Object does not support this property or method`.  Here is the code that is failing:

```
ActiveSheet.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
   Destination:=Windows("Some Report").Worksheets( _
                                 "Some Sheet").Range("A1").Values
```

I've tried different variations but receive the same error.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work as I wanted.  What I did get to work was simply setting one range equal to another;    Workbook("Some Report").Worksheets( "Some Sheet").Range("A1:ZZ100").Values  = Workbook("Some Report 2").Worksheets( "Some Sheet 2").Range("A1:ZZ100").Values.  This works just fine but I have not been able to get it to work with filtered ranges.  Anyone able to do this without having to cycle through each visible row?

Answer (score 1):

What about just setting the cells.value equal to each other?  This little snippet assumes you want to copy the cells into the same destination cell, so you'd have to adjust for that if that's not what you're doing.

```
Private Sub worksheet_selectionchange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Integer

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb1.Sheets(2)

    lastRow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lastCol = ws1.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    For i = 1 To lastRow: For j = 1 To lastCol
        If ws1.Cells(i, j).Value > 5 And Not ws1.Cells(i, j).Hidden Then
            ws2.Cells(i, j).Value = ws1.Cells(i, j).Value
        End If
    Next: Next

End Sub
```

Unfortunately without seeing much else of your code I can't prove much else, but this is the only alternative to copying and pasting that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this without actually using the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) method and it copies and pastes perfectly. I first filter the data with an array, then I just use the Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:" & last column & last row).Copy destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E5") method and it works just fine on Office 2010. I did look into the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) method but it was never necessary.

Maybe if you put UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy it would work?